# Model popup is not showing in Blazor with @ref attribute

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a shared component for Model popup and using @ref attribute while registering the component. I am not getting any error but my model popup is not showing.

Below the code for CofirmationBox

```
@inherits ConfirmModelBoxBase

@if (ShowConfirmationBox)
{

<div class="modal fade show d-block" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure want to delete the record?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}


 public class ConfirmModelBoxBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public bool ShowConfirmationBox { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> CoonfirmationChanged { get; set; }

    public void Show()
    {
        ShowConfirmationBox = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Registering the Component on My employee list page

```
 <ConfirmModelBoxBase @ref="DeleteConfirmation">

 </ConfirmModelBoxBase>
```

Server side call to show the popup

```
[Parameter] public ConfirmModelBoxBase DeleteConfirmation { get; set; }

protected void btnDelete_Click()
    {
        DeleteConfirmation.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Is your Razor component name same as your code base file i.e. ConfirmModelBoxBase or is it ConfirmModelBox?

Comment: My razor page name is "ConfirmModelBox.razor" and base class name is "ConfirmModelBoxBase.razor"

Comment: Hi Everyone, I found the issue and resolved it. The problem was my Component Name which i was regitering on page. <ConfirmModelBoxBase @ref="DeleteConfirmation" /> changed to <ConfirmModelBox @ref="DeleteConfirmation" />.

Answer (score 2):

According to your HTML code, you use [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/).
You don't need a @ref to open it but some JSInterop:

1. Add a scripts tags in your *_Host.html* or *index.hmtl* to load bootstrap js and its dependency. Bootstrap js required JQuery and Popper.js.

```html
<head>
...
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

2. Add a js interop file in your wwwroot folder

**bootstrapInteropt.js**

```js
window.bootstrapInteropt = {
    showModal: id => {
        $(`#${id}`).modal('show');
    },
    hideModal: id => {
        $(`#${id}`).modal('hide');
    }
};
```

3. Add a script tag to load this js in your *_Host.html* or *index.hmtl*

```html
<body>
    <app>
    </app>
    <script src="bootstrapInteropt.js"></script>
...
</body>
```

4. Call the js fonction to show the popup

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure want to delete the record?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> CoonfirmationChanged { get; set; }

    public Task Show()
    {
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("bootstrapInteropt.showModal", "exampleModal");
    }

    public Task Hide()
    {
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("bootstrapInteropt.hideModal", "exampleModal");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. how i will get get the confirmation data from model popup to the class.

Comment: Open another question, it's not related to this one

Comment: @ArunSingh basically like a classic Blazor component, using data binding, event callback and/or service injection.

Comment: @ArunSingh sample here : https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/BlazorApp/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp.Components/DeleteEntityButton.razor

Answer (score 1):

I believe the pattern is to use the property + "Changed" for the EventCallback.

```
[Parameter] public bool ShowConfirmationBox { get; set; }

[Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ShowConfirmationBoxChanged { get; set; }
```

I created a simplified version of this code at https://blazorfiddle.com/s/hd6sbj44

Comment: Yes, Your model popup is not getting closed or cancel?

Comment: Created a new fiddle with a Hide function following your Show function pattern at https://blazorfiddle.com/s/z76r47t9

Answer (score 0):

You can user JSInterop, agua from mars was showing in the answer. If you want to avoid JSInterop you can try this

```
 public class ConfirmModelBoxBase : ComponentBase
    {
        //[Parameter] // You don't need because you are not passing the argument with Component you are updating using Show function 
        public bool ShowConfirmationBox { get; set; }

        //[Parameter] // You don't need
        //public EventCallback<bool> ShowConfirmationBoxChanged { get; set; }


        public void Show()
        {
            ShowConfirmationBox = true;

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

ConfirmDelete.razor which will inherit ConfirmModelBoxBase

```
@*ConfirmDelete.razor*@

@inherits ConfirmModelBoxBase

@if (ShowConfirmationBox)
{
    <div class="modal fade show d-block" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="OnCanceled">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure want to delete the recored?
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="OnCanceled">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="OnSaved">Save Changed</button>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
}

@code {

    private void OnCanceled(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowConfirmationBox = false;
    }

    private void OnSaved(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowConfirmationBox = false;

        //Save changes
    }

}
```

Sample.razor

```
<ConfirmDelete @ref="_confirm">

</ConfirmDelete>

<button @onclick="OnClicked">Click</button>

@code{
    private ConfirmModelBoxBase _confirm;

    private void OnClicked()
    {
        _confirm.Show();
    }
}
```